# Get checkbox is check or not without js

Tags: java, forms, jsp, spring-mvc, checkbox

I have a form with a checkbox input:

```
<form:input id="garder_${indice}" path="mesFormulaires[${indice}].garder"
    type="text" name="garder_${indice}" />
```

I want to get if the checkbox is checked or not in Java. How is it possible, using getter/setter with a boolean named "garder". I hope it's possible with Java methods, but I don't know them.

Comment: are you using any framework or core JSP/Servlet ?

Comment: Im' using spring MVC, and use the getter/setter into my controller. Works for a simple textbox input but don't with my checkbox.

Comment: _but don't with my checkbox_ plese elaborate

Comment: Well, i can get and use easyly a input text in my controller, but with a checkbox, I always get value false for my checkbox. Is that clearer?

Comment: If the checkbox is checked it will set the value in request otherwise it won't , So you should recieve true incase of checked checkbox, check the request being generated with firebug

Comment: It will come through in the parameter map as `name->on` rather than `name->true`, but other than that, agree with @JigarJoshi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Spring MVC I suggest you to use the `form:checkbox` tag and bind it to a property of the `modelAttribute` object of your form.

```
public class YourModelAttribute{
    private boolan checkBoxProp;
    // other props

    // getter and setter for your props
}
```

Then in your page:

```
<form:checkbox id="ckbId" path="checkBoxProp" />
```

Be sure to set as `modelAttribute` of your form an instance of `YourModelAttribute`.

Comment: Thank you. It was so simple, I was thinking that put form:checkbox will makes no difference.